# can I run android project without AVD

Tags: android

I want to run android project at backend without using any UI. No activity, AVD required. Is it feasible?
Thanks in Advance !

Comment: How can you run Android code without an android device?

Answer (score 1):

1. If your project does not have an Activity, that should be a Service. Services do not need a Screen, and it can run in background. (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html)
2. Then, if you are developing a library, you can distribute the JAR file among other developers, and to test the library, you have to develop an App that uses your library.
3. To run an Android app, you need either a real **Android device** or an **AVD** (Android Virtual Device). To read more on how to set-up a real android phone to run your project, see http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#setting-up

Answer (score -1):

If it's a library, the answer is `Yes`.

Comment: Only YES..please if you got any..provide discription about how possible with library and how to do that..and would be great if you also can tell how it's not possible if not library..

Comment: It is not an library , its just a java file to run some code on Android platform ... I think using Service would work,,,